# unrecognized selector for category

Tags: ios, hyperlink, frameworks, categories

In framework1, there is a private category of classA. If I use framework1 in app directly, everything is fine.

If I link framework1 and some other frameworks using '-ObjC' and '-framework framework1' link flag to generate a compound framework2. When I use framework2 in app, it crashes for not founding the methods defined in category of classA.

Using nm command to check the binary object of framework2, I can find the private category.

It's really weird and I don't know why.

The code is something like this.

Framework1 -> classA.m

```
@interface classA(Private)
+ (void)method1;
@end

@implementation classA(Private)
+ (void)method1{}
@end

@implementation classA
+ (void)method2
{
  [self method1];
}
@end
```

Then I compile Framework1 as relocatable format.

In Framework2, I import Framework1. Add "-ObjC" and "-framework Framework1". Then compile Framework2 as relocatable.

Using Framework2 in an app, compile and run is OK. But when method2 of classA is triggered, the app crashes for not founding method1. If I use Framework1 directly in app, everything is fine.

Issue closed!
I figured out that if all frameworks are compiled as static and embed framework1 in framework2 using other librarian flags. And add -ObjC flag to the last app demo. Everything goes fine. All categories are loaded.

Comment: Are you exposing and importing the correct header files?

Comment: YES，after combining the frameworks into one, I postprocess the headers for referencing. The private category of classA is used internally by other methods of classA and not public.

Comment: Framework1 is built as relocatable-object file and the combined framework2 is relocatable-object format too.

Answer (score 0):

Issue closed! I figured out that if all frameworks are compiled as static and embed framework1 in framework2 using other librarian flags. And add -ObjC flag to the last app demo. Everything goes fine. All categories are loaded.